# Inserting into a Priority queue

Tags: java, object, priority-queue

I've been given a task of making a priority queue from scratch without extension programs.

The underlying task in hand is to create a priority queue for an IT ticketing System that allows the IT workers to prioritize which tasks within the company must be completed first . (priority = 1 -> Highest priority and 4 being the lowest).

I'm attempting to do this via a singly linked list.

My issue in hand is once my insertInQueue(Ticket T) function takes the last value in it fails.

The failure return statement is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at Queue.insertInQueue(Queue.java:36)
```

(the line of code at line 36):

```
`if( temp.getNextTicket().getPriority() > T.getPriority())
```

`at Main.main(Main.java:21)` (The last object to go into the system)

```
private Ticket head;
private Ticket tail;




public void insertInQueue(Ticket T){ 

    Ticket temp = head;

    if(head == null){       //When no values are in the queue
        head = T;           //head = Ticket
        tail = T;           //tail = Ticket

    }else if(T.getNextTicket() == null){

            tail.setNextTicket(T);
            tail = T;


    }   


    else{
        while( temp != null ){

            if( temp.getNextTicket().getPriority() > T.getPriority()){

                T.setNextTicket(temp.getNextTicket());
                temp.setNextTicket(T);


            }
            temp = temp.getNextTicket();


            }
        }

    }
```

Example of input:

```
Ticket T8 = new Ticket(8, "Ben_DG", 4);
```

I've tried a few different things but havn't gotten anywhere. Would anybody be able to help me out?

If you need more of my code let me know and I'll post it up. (just a little concerned some class mates would steal it)

Thanks!

Comment: At some point `temp.getNextTicket()` is returning null in the `while (temp != null)` loop. So, you must check for `temp.getNextTicket()` not being null.

Comment: @Kevin0 Do you mean set while loop to temp.getNextTicket()!=null or do you mean check somewhere before that to not allow it to get to the while loop

Comment: The loop does `while (temp != null)`, but then there is `if (temp.getNextTicket().getPriority()`. However, based upon other code, `temp.getNextTicket()` can return null, so the chained call will fail. I didn't read all of the logic, but a simple fix would be `if (temp.getNextTicket() != null && temp.getNextTicket().getPriority > T.getPriority()) { ...`. This approach will fix, I think, the NPE, but there could be other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the rest of the code for what set and get next ticket, I can't tell for sure, but logically at some point you are trying to get a NULL value with your get method which is giving you the error. Check all your conditionals properly and see if you aren't trying to get a NULL value.

That should be the main issue and should fix it

Comment: `public Ticket getNextTicket(){
        
        return this.nextTicket;
    }
`


`public void setNextTicket(Ticket nextTicket){
        
        this.nextTicket = nextTicket;
    }

`

Comment: Yes, it's as I thought, a simple assignment and return type functions, so probably at some point in your insertInQueue function you are referencing a NULL variable

Comment: I see where the problem is @Ben, In your while statement you are looping all the way to the node before it becomes NULL, so after that if you execute temp.getNextTicket() function that will reference to a NULL variable hence giving you the error.